# Is it possible to get a selector using indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like

```
    <div id="box_1">
    <div id="box_2">
    <div id="box_3">
```

If i want to get all id's starting with 'box_' how can i do it something like this..

```
    $("#box_" + anything )
```

Unfortunately wrapping the div's won't work because it will get all the other divs in side and between the box divs.

I guess i can give them all another class and reference it like that, but just wondering if there's something like this out there.. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("div[id^=box_]");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector as others have mentioned, but it might be better to give each element a class:

```
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
```

Select with:

```
$(".box")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep:

```
$('div[id^="box_"]');
```

In this case, because you are trying to use the ID selector, its better to switch to an element selector, combined with an attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^="box_"')
```

That will give you all elements whose id [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) "box_". If you need to, qualify it with an element:

```
$('div[id^="box_"')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know whether it starts or endswith any string then you can try `*=` selector which will look within the attribute value.

```
$("div[id*='box_']");
```